# Magento emails are not going

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am working on MAGENTO 1.9.2.4 Emails are not going in it through zend mail and php mail function even testMail emails also are not going.I have then send mails through PHP Mailer and tested it,test mail working fine with it.

Installed SMTP Pro extension showing following error:

SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: care@onestopretail.in from: care@onestopretail.in. Unable to send test email.
Your connection to the SMTP server timed out. Please check with your host that outbound SMTP connections are allowed as this error is most commonly caused when a host blocks outbound connections. This is probably not a bug, please do not email extension support until you have checked with your server admin or host.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Comment: You can take this reference http://www.aschroder.com/2011/06/smtp-pro-with-magento-a-sort-of-user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Login your google account from your browser and go to below link

https://myaccount.google.com/security#activity

and set below setting to `on` shown in image

[image]

Comment: This solution is not workin,problem is still the same.

Comment: I am also trying to send mail but its showing error. Error is- Your connection to the SMTP server timed out. Please check with your host that outbound SMTP connections are allowed as this error is most commonly caused when a host blocks outbound connections. This is probably not a bug, please do not email extension support until you have checked with your server admin or host.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.
Required database tables exist.